# memory leak from numberWithInt?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I think my program is leaking memory in the last line of this loop but i dont see why it should. Im not calling alloc. Can anyone explain this? I know it might be a really obvious answer but Im just getting started with objective C. Is it just that the numberWithInt call adds a +1 retain or something? Thanks

```
for (int k=0; k<=27; k++) {
    NSNumber *zero= [NSNumber numberWithInt:0];
    [randomUsed insertObject:zero atIndex:k];
    [alphaKeys insertObject:zero atIndex:k];
}
```

Comment: That snippet does nothing wrong, unless it's not having an autorelease pool around it for some reason. Why do you think the source of the leak is there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code that you have here doesn't have any leak.

You must think in term of ownership. You don't own `zero` here since it was not returned from a `alloc` or `new`. Since you don't own it, you don't need to `release`it.

What you're thinking is that `insertObject:` is increasing the `retainCount`, which is true. When you insert `zero`into your arrays, `randomUsed` and `alphaKeys` retains your zero object. In this case, it's the arrays that own it, not you. *They* need to release it, not you.

If there's a leak, it's the array themselves that are leaking, not your `zero` object.

Please review the [cocoa memory management guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html).